# How to get a file from a server in a cluster in Vsphere using pyVmomi to remote(host) pc

Tags: python-3.x, server, vmware, vsphere, pyvmomi

I am able to execute a command inside the server but I want to get that output in my local pc. I don't want want to use ssh keys. I want to use just the host's username and password as well as vm's(server's) username and password. I couldn't find a direct method to get the shell output of server in my pc, but this method seems half done like generate and save the output in server and then get the file from server. I am finding it difficult to get file(sample.txt) from server to local host(pc).

[EDIT: I am able to do this using via via method(Store the output to server and then get it back into local pc, is there a direct method ?) ]

```
from pyVim import connect
from config import *
from pyVmomi import vim, vmodl
import ssl

service_instance = connect.SmartConnect(host="yyyyyyy", port=some_number,user="xxx" , pwd=pwd,sslContext=ssl._create_unverified_context())
content = service_instance.RetrieveContent()

vm = searcher.FindByIp(ip="zzzzzz", vmSearch=True)

creds = vim.vm.guest.NamePasswordAuthentication(username='root', password=vmpwd)

pm = service_instance.content.guestOperationsManager.processManager

#checks python version and stores in sample.txt in server
ps = vim.vm.guest.ProcessManager.ProgramSpec(programPath='/usr/bin/python', arguments='--version  &> sample.txt') 
res = pm.StartProgramInGuest(vm, creds, ps)
print(res) #Prints pid
```

Comment: I think only way is to save a file as you told sample.txt and then fetch the file using module GuestFileManager.InitiateFileTransferFromGues. More info in this thread https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/issues/264

Comment: Ya I was able to do that. But can it be possible to get the output directly to my console or saving into my local directory rather than saving into the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the job but I would appreciate if someone knows how to directly get the output of shell command from server to my local pc. This code makes a file with the output of cmd inside the server and it gets copied into my local pc

```
from pyVim import connect
from config import *
from pyVmomi import vim, vmodl
import ssl
import os
import requests

service_instance = connect.SmartConnect(host="xxxx", port=aaa,user="yyy" , pwd=pwd,sslContext=ssl._create_unverified_context())

content = service_instance.RetrieveContent()

# # Find a VM
vm = searcher.FindByIp(ip="aaaa", vmSearch=True)

creds = vim.vm.guest.NamePasswordAuthentication(username='root', password=vmpwd)

pm = service_instance.content.guestOperationsManager.processManager


#executes and saves sample.txt into server
ps = vim.vm.guest.ProcessManager.ProgramSpec(programPath='/usr/bin/python', arguments='--version  &> sample.txt')
res = pm.StartProgramInGuest(vm, creds, ps)

dest="/Users/username/Desktop/vcenter/sample.txt" #My local pc

src="/root/sample.txt" #Server's directory
fti = content.guestOperationsManager.fileManager.InitiateFileTransferFromGuest(vm, creds, src)

resp=requests.get(fti.url, verify=False)

#Writes into file
with open(dest, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(resp.content)
```

Comment: I did not find a `searcher` object in script. Instead, `content.searchIndex` worked for me in place.

Comment: This method isn't working for .zip files. I am getting following error: 
 
```UnicodeEncodeError: codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)```    Any suggestion ?