# How to determine the OS version using pvymomi?

Tags: python-3.x, vsphere

Using pvymomi, I can determine the OS.  How does one determine the OS version?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import atexit
from pyVmomi       import vim
from pyVim.connect import SmartConnectNoSSL, Disconnect

si = SmartConnectNoSSL(host = 'xxx', user = 'xxx', pwd = 'xxx', port = 443)
atexit.register(Disconnect, si)
content = si.RetrieveContent()
vm = si.content.searchIndex.FindByIp(None, sys.argv[1], True)

print(vm.summary.config.guestFullName)
print(vm.summary.config.guestId)
```

The above code produces the following:

```
$ ./example.py  10.120.73.45
CentOS 7 (64-bit)
centos7_64Guest
```

I can see the VM is running CentOS 7, but is it 7.6 or 7.9? I'm not seeing what property or even what data object gives that information.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the ```platform``` module.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research into this question, I have found that the `vSphere Web Services API,` which the Python package `pyvmomi` uses ***does not*** have an easy way to collect the exact version operating system version with a basic API call.

If you look at the [vSphere Web Services API](https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/b50dcbbf-051d-4204-a3e7-e1b618c1e384/538cf2ec-b34f-4bae-a332-3820ef9e7773/vim.vm.GuestInfo.html) information for
`guestFamily`, which is in `GuestInfo` you will not see any API call for precise versioning information.

[image]

Additionally, to obtain the exact operating system version information for CentOS you would normally have to query the kernel, which contains this information.

[image]

You can obtain the version of CentOS using this command:

```
cat /etc/centos-release
# output 
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
```

You can query this information [GuestProgramSpec](https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/b525fb12-61bb-4ede-b9e3-c4a1f8171510/99ba073a-60e9-4933-8690-149860ce8754/doc/vim.vm.guest.ProcessManager.ProgramSpec.html)

Here is some pseudocode for doing this.

```
ps = vim.vm.guest.ProcessManager.ProgramSpec(programPath="/usr/bin/cat", arguments=" /etc/centos-release > /tmp/os_version_info.txt")
res = pm.StartProgramInGuest(vm, creds, ps)
```

You can also obtain this information using the `uname` tool, which is commonly used to obtain information about the processor architecture, which as the system hostname and the version of the kernel running on the system.

Here is the command -  `uname -s -r`

- -s, (--kernel-name) - Prints the kernel name
- -r, (--kernel-release) - Prints the kernel release.

Here is a [website](https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/150469/list-of-linux-distributions-and-kernels.html) that provides some information on mapping the kernel releases information to a specific operating system. Here is another [website](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=kernel-x86_64). Using the latter website I can see that `kernel-3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64` maps to `CentOS 7.9.2009 for x86_64.`

Here is some pseudocode for doing this.

```
ps = vim.vm.guest.ProcessManager.ProgramSpec(programPath="/usr/bin/uname", arguments=" -s -r > /tmp/os_kernel_info.txt")
res = pm.StartProgramInGuest(vm, creds, ps)
```

Based on my research getting this information back to the console is more complex.  Here is a [Stack Overflow question in how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60318680/how-to-get-a-file-from-a-server-in-a-cluster-in-vsphere-using-pyvmomi-to-remote).

**UPDATE**

I discovered this sample `pyvmomi` script, which can execute a command and retrieve the content back to the console.

- [Execute program in a virtual machine](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/blob/master/samples/execute_program_in_vm.py)

Comment: The above executes the command, but does not return the results.

Comment: @user2569618 It's hard to provide feedback without more details.  Please provide me details on which command you're referring to.  Also provide me the details on how you used the command in your code.

Comment: Apologies.  The above psuedo code turned into actual code returns the PID of the executed command, not the results of the command.  There's still no getting back the OS version.  e.g. `creds = vim.vm.guest.NamePasswordAuthentication(username=username, password=password)
cmdspec = vim.vm.guest.ProcessManager.ProgramSpec(arguments='/etc/centos-release | tee /tmp/os_verision_info.txt', programPath='/usr/bin/cat')
cmdpid = content.guestOperationsManager.processManager.StartProgramInGuest(vm=vm, auth=creds, spec=cmdspec)
 `

Comment: @user2569618  The `res` is the PID, but the file `os_verision_info.txt` was created.  You need to transfer that file to your system.  That is accomplished using https://www.vmware.com/support/orchestrator/doc/vco_vsphere55_api/html/VcGuestFileManager.html#initiateFileTransferFromGuest.

Comment: Which means that a user/password is needed, which is not an option.  Unfortunately, the answer you provided is not answer.

Comment: ***What do you mean that a user/password is not an option?*** You had to provide that information to run the commands to get the OS info. ref: pm.StartProgramInGuest(vm, creds, ps). NOTE the `creds` in this line of code, which is a user/password combo. ***So what you are saying is incorrect, because you're already using a username and password.***